# Parameter assigned with default (= default) means?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to understand the precondition function and came across the "= default". A quick google and scanning the guide did not bring any result related. Could anyone explain this to me? Thanks.

```
func precondition(condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = default, file: StaticString = default, line: UWord = default)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything. What you're seeing is due to a bug in the way the headers are translated into Swift. There is a default value here but you are not being shown what it is.

Another case in point in the headers is the recurring refrain `where S.Generator.Element == S.Generator.Element`. It's just an erroneous byproduct of the automatic translation process, and has been acknowledged as such by Apple.

Comment: Is this really a bug, not just a feature (that it shows a default parameter is used, but not its value, which may change)? Where has Apple acknowledged that it's erroneous?

Comment: @jtbandes I had this info direct from Chris Lattner on the old Apple forum. The bug has been corrected and the phrase which this question is about no longer appears in the headers.

Comment: I asked because other questions are being closed as dupes (and [dupes of dupes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530678/swift-set-default-as-default-parameter)) of this one. It would be nice to update it with the latest info (if there's any change) and links to sources.

Comment: @jtbandes Vote to delete it if you don't like it. This question is from 2014! If people don't understand it's old, and if they aren't aware of the fact that Swift is in constant flux, I shudder to think how they're going to deal with Swift 3 starting next week!

Comment: I understand the sentiment, but I'm not convinced that `= default` is an error, it makes sense to me that this is what would appear in generated headers. So I don't think this is particularly outdated. (Also can't vote to delete positive-score questions.)

Comment: Well, then downvote my answer if you don't think it's right. I won't hold it against you; you're a free agent, and besides, I respect your work. It just happens that in this case I don't agree with you. Or even give your own answer if you think you have a better one!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as e.g.

```
func precondition(condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "default", file: StaticString = "default", line: UWord = 2)
```

to make an example to matt's answer

Comment: More likely: `func precondition(condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "", file: StaticString = __FILE__, line: UWord = __LINE__)` – compare https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=15.

Comment: Whatever ;-) It's just an example to show that the default is not a keyword but some concrete value.